# set properties on rectangle request. iOS, Swift

Tags: ios, swift

Im trying to set properties on a rectangle request.
Im trying to set minimum size, aspect ratio and others but get the error below.

> Fatal error: Attempted to read an unowned reference but the object was already deallocated2018-08-13 16:08:09.081049+0100 app[4000:1277980] Fatal error: Attempted to read an unowned reference but the object was already deallocated

```
func performVisionRequest(image: CGImage, orientation: CGImagePropertyOrientation) {

    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
        do {
            let imageRequestHandler = VNImageRequestHandler(cgImage: image, orientation: orientation, options: [:])
            try imageRequestHandler.perform(
                [VNDetectRectanglesRequest(completionHandler:{ req, err in
                    self.rectanglesRequest(request:req, error:err)

                })]
            )
        } catch let error as NSError {
            self.sliceCompletion([UIImage]())
            print("Failed to perform vision request: \(error)")

        }
    }
}

func rectanglesRequest(request: VNRequest, error: Error?) {
    if let err = error as NSError? {
        noRect = true
        var slices = [imageNo]
        self.sliceCompletion(slices as! [UIImage])
        slices = []
        print("Failed during detection: \(err.localizedDescription)")
        return
    }
    unowned let rectanglesRequestSet = VNDetectRectanglesRequest()

    rectanglesRequestSet.minimumSize = 0.07
    rectanglesRequestSet.minimumAspectRatio = 0.2
    rectanglesRequestSet.maximumAspectRatio = 0.3
    rectanglesRequestSet.quadratureTolerance = 22.0
```

Comment: `unowned let rectanglesRequestSet = VNDetectRectanglesRequest()` Why `unowned`? Is there some kind of concern that there's a retain cycle involving `rectanglesRequestSet` because nothing in the code shared would cause one.

Comment: Yes I wanted to make sure as I am still learning

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here it is not good to mark `rectanglesRequestSet` as `unowned`, as it is causing it to be released before you can use it and when you attempt to message a released `unowned` object you will get a crash, which is explains the message you get:

> Attempted to read an unowned reference but the object was already deallocated

`unowned` is used to break retain cycles which occur when a class's property holds a reference back to class itself, often through a closure. For example:

```
class ViewControllerA: UIViewController {
    let viewControllerB = UIViewControllerB()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        viewControllerB.onSelect = {
            self.onSelection() 
        }
    }

    func onSelection() {
        // do something
    }
}

class ViewControllerB: UIViewController {
    var onSelect: (() -> Void)?
}
```

For example the code above creates a retain cycle as `vcA` -> `vcB` -> `onSelect` -> `vcA`, where `vcA` is an instance of `ViewControllerA` and `vcB` is an instance of `ViewControllerB`. `vcA` and `vcB` will never be released as `vcA` holds a reference to `vcB` by virtue of it being a property. And, `vcB` holds a reference to `vcA` by virtue of variable capture in the `onSelect` closure. This happens because in order for closures to execute code in the future they must hold a reference to all of the objects used in the closure, in the example `vcA` is the only object used so the closure holds a reference to it and `vcB` holds a reference to the closure. To prevent this retain cycle:

```
viewControllerB.onSelect = { [unowned self]
    self.onSelection() 
}
```

or

```
viewControllerB.onSelect = { [weak self]
    self?.onSelection() 
}
```

will cause the closure to not capture `vcA` meaning there will be no retain cycle. It is safer to use `weak` rather than `unowned`. The closure can't guarantee that un-captured objects will be around at execution `weak` will allow such objects to be `nil`, `unowned` is, in a manner, stipulating that it won't be `nil` and instructing the program to crash if it is.

Comment: Thank you for the info and explanation